# What's the advantage of locale archives over locale files spread out in directories?

Tags: filesystems, locale, glibc

I am quite curious about why `locale-archive` files are preferred in many Linux distros and what and to which extent its advantage over compiled files for each locale would be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The locale-archive files contain the languages used
over the system  man pages for example. This memory-mapping enables
reading the file as it's in memory, avoiding system calls
used to perform disk-read operations, therefore it can result in much faster
access.

[Memory-mapped files](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory-mapped_file) (like shared libraries) are kind of 
part of the virtual memory of processes like the [top](http://linux.die.net/man/1/top) command, VIRT
field.

So, the part of the locale-archive file mapped to
memory adds up to the virtual memory of every processes that makes use
of glibc (basically everything), while this is actually only once in
memory.

At last, for each processes, the virtual memory
overestimates the real memory of the process by, the amount of  part of
the locale-archive file which is memory-mapped.

Answer (score 0):

Performance.

The locale files under `/usr/share/i18n` are text files that require some parsing. Each process that loads them would have to do the parsing.

`locale-archive` is in a binary format that's closer to how applications access the data in memory. There's essentially no parsing needed: just open the file and read the data structures (or rather, in fact, [map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mmap) the file into memory).

In addition, the memory-mapped file can be shared between processes, so this saves memory compared to a scheme where each process has to parse the files and build its own copy of the in-memory data structures.

Having a single large file rather than many small files makes it faster to load all the relevant data: there's a single file to open, no need to enumerate the files in directories and so on.